# Get max column length for each column in a table represented by a list of Dictionaries

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I have a table represented as a `List` of `Dictionary` of `KeyValue` pairs.

Each dictionary in the list represents a row in the table, and has the same set of keys (the column names). For each key, the value is the column value in the current row.

Now, I'm trying to write an elegant lambda expression to calculate max column length for each column in the table.

Here is how i do it today:

```
// Get max column lengths
var maxColumnLengths = new Dictionary<string, int>();
foreach (var row in dics)
{
    foreach (var col in row)
    {
        if (!maxColumnLengths.ContainsKey(col.Key))
        {
            maxColumnLengths.Add(col.Key, 0);
        }

        if (maxColumnLengths[col.Key] < col.Value.ToString().Length)
        {
            maxColumnLengths[col.Key] = col.Value.ToString().Length;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to make it into a 1/2 liner lambda expression. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in single LINQ query:

```
var source = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();

// (...)

var maxColumnLengths = source.SelectMany(x => x)
                             .GroupBy(x => x.Key)
                             .ToDictionary(g => g.Key,
                                           g => g.Max(x => x.Value.ToString().Length));
```